# Converting PHP Contact Form to SMTP

Tags: php, html, forms, email, smtp

had alot fo problems making a functional contact form tonight. After messing for hours i finally found out that i can only use SMTP with my web hoster.

Can anyone please advice me how i can complete my form?

This is my current SMTP PHP Form

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();

//Your SMTP servers details

$mail->IsSMTP();               // set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = "localhost";  // specify main and backup server or localhost
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "enquiries@c(hidden)y.co.uk";  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "******"; // SMTP password
//It should be same as that of the SMTP user

$redirect_url = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; //Redirect URL after submit the form

$mail->From = $mail->Username;  //Default From email same as smtp user
$mail->FromName = "Display Name";

$mail->AddAddress("enquiries@c(hidden)y.co.uk", "chapnolo"); //Email address where you wish to receive/collect those emails.

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = "Name of the requestor :".$_POST['fullname']." \r\n <br>Email Adrress :".$_POST['email']." \r\n <br> Query :".$_POST['query'];
$mail->Body    = $message;

if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo "Message has been sent";
header("Location: $redirect_url");
}
?>
```

I need my form to have the following functionality for me to retrieve the requires e-mail message body.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$web = $_POST['web'];


$formcontent="From: $name \n Contact: $number \n Website: $web \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "enquiries@c(hidden)y.co.uk";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email ";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!" . " -" . "<a href='contact.html' style='text-decoration:none;color:#ff0099;'> Return Home</a>";
```

Help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: What error are you encountering?

Comment: There is no error. The top script works. But it doesnt have the functionality as i need it to send me the name, contact number, email and message body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metexora - So you're not having any issues with the code, you just haven't told it to send you the name contact number, email and message body - just change:

```
$message = "Name of the requestor :".$_POST['fullname']." \r\n <br>Email Adrress :".$_POST['email']." \r\n <br> Query :".$_POST['query'];
```

to

```
$message = "Name of the requestor :".$name." \r\n <br>Email Adrress :".$email." \r\n <br> Phone number :".$number."\r\n <br> Message: ".$message."\r\n <br> Website: ".$web;
```

(Note: Be careful, you are re-declaring $message here, that isn't really recommended practise given they refer to different things, the user message and the email message, you should only use the change the contents of a variable if it still refers to the same thing)

Comment: Hm, I've done this but when submitting my form its just taking me to a blank screen with the Url of "http://www.c*(hidden)*gy.co.uk/mail.php

Comment: Well that's surprising. It's set by `$redirect_url = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; //Redirect URL after submit the form` to redirect to the root URL (server home page), not the script. Maybe try removing the redirect, see if it now echos the text.

If you could share the code you now have as one piece, I could review it for you further, but it was a little hard to decipher the two pieces you first sent through.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951198/smtp-contact-form-blank-screen-on-submit  I've posted another with my current code.